# Email on BlackBerry displaying neither HTML nor Text version

Tags: blackberry, html-email

Has anyone encountered this issue where on BlackBerry Bold (and possibly other similar models) is not displaying the provided HTML nor the text version of an email?

Instead it displays its own version, along the lines of the following:

```
[Sent by: "Name"]

[email@address.com]

<<image 1>>[Link:http://urlhere.com/img.gif]
Text from the email 
<<image 2>>[Link:http://urlhere.com/img.gif]
```

- Yes, HTML is enabled
- Yes, it does successfully receive other HTML emails

The particular email I am working on, and *sadly cannot share all the code*, is responsive. Once I remove the snippet of code that makes it responsive, the email does display properly. Here is the CSS in question: http://jsfiddle.net/kjGg5/1/

However, I have sent other responsive emails to this exact same BlackBerry and they have worked.

Apologies for the lack of code, but even if someone else has seen this issue that would be a start.

Also, when the email is forwarded, it is blank. I don't know if this is related.

Comment: When you say responsive, it means you are integrating with the native email screen (by using a ViewListener) or with you are fiddling with the incoming message by modifying its headers / content etc?

Comment: I am using CSS media queries to display email content in a manner optimized for viewing on various screen sizes. Similar to this template from Email on Acid - http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/emailology/2013/Responsive_Template1.html

Comment: So this code that you mention about commenting is in Java or css/html?

Comment: It is a CSS media query which looks like this - http://jsfiddle.net/kjGg5/1/

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question in their search, as I did, I later found this post that maybe sheds some more light on the issue: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_viewport_metatag_rendered_unusable

Removing that tag fixed the display of my emails on BlackBerry devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after numerous tests, it seems that Blackberry chokes if the HTML header is over a certain size. I'm still not certain what that size is, but if anyone in the future has this issue, try trimming down your HTML header size.

Update: After some testing it seems the max HTML header size for and email to render properly on Blackberry is 7.5kb.

Comment: Not sure if related but BlackBerry only sends 10kb data to the device in case of an html mail and 2kb in case of a plain text mail.

Comment: Interesting, I sent an email that was 79k and then another that was 129k and both rendered properly after I had paired down the size of the HTML header. Perhaps my HTML header was over 10k before.

Comment: Well, it seems the emails that were successfully rendered had were less than 7.5kb in the head of the HTML email, and those that displayed the hybrid version were over 7.5kb. Possibly the remaining 2.5kb is utilized elsewhere by the email platform.